# Gerar numero sequencial de 8 digitos

Tags: php

Preciso gerar um numero sequencial de 8 digitos seguindo o banco..

Tenho a coluna código na tabela orcamento, possui o valor de ex: 1800000001 onde 18 é o ano e o restante é um numero sequencial, preciso que eu verifique no sistema qual o ultimo orcamento cadastrado e crie um numero sequencial seguinte, no exemplo é 1800000001, quero que gere o codigo 1800000002 e assim sucessivamente, contanto que quando o ultimo numero atingir dois digitos ele substitua um 0, quando 3, dois zeros, ex: 1800000099, esse numero após o ano tem que conter 8 casas.

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: O problema é que não sei como gera o numero dessa forma..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um `SELECT` para saber qual o último código inserido:

```
$sql="SELECT codigo FROM sua_tabela ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1";

$ultimo_resultado='1800000001';
$ultimo_resultado=intval($ultimo_resultado)+1;
//1800000002
```

O primeiro número, você pode verificar no sistema se existe algum registro, caso não exista vc define manualmente mesmo usando um `if`, subsequentemente serão definidos automaticamente.

```
$ano=date('y');//pega o ano corrente no formato 19, como no seu código
if(!resultados){//verifica se não existem resultados do sql
    $primeiro_codigo=$ano.00000001;//cria o primeiro, no caso 18
}else{//se tiver resultados
    $ano_atual=substr($ultimo_codigo,0,2);//pega o ano atual do ultimo código
    if($ano_atual != $ano){//compara com o ano corrente
        $primeiro_codigo=$ano.00000001;//se for diferente cria o código novo, quando passar para 2019
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sim, pensei desta mesma forma, mas e quando virar o ano, que não vai encontrar nenhum codigo com o ano 19? Como criarei esse codigo de x digitos?

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Ótimo meu amigo, isso que precisava, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar um padrão em PHP seria:

```
$ultimoNro = '1800000001';
$ultimoNro = substr($ultimoNro, 2);
$proximoNro = $ultimoNro + 1;
$proximoNro = date('y').str_pad($proximoNro, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $proximoNro;
```